# extract first p tag and first h1 tag with commonmark

Tags: javascript, html, commonmark

Suppose i have the following markdown

```js
# Comman mark is **just great**
You can try CommonMark here.  This dingus is powered by
[commonmark.js](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js), the
JavaScript reference implementation.
## Try CommonMark
1. item one
2. item two
   - sublist
   - sublist
```

I want to get the first `h1` tag and first `p` tag for making them title and description of the post receptively.

> I can not use browser API, because it is running on the Node server

To get the first `h1` tag, I used `commonmark.js`.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  let parsed = reader.parse(md);
  let result = writer.render(parsed);

  let walker = parsed.walker();
  let event, node;

  while ((event = walker.next())) {
    node = event.node;

    // h1 tags
    if (event.entering && node.type === 'heading' && node.level == 1) {
      console.log('h1', '--', node?.firstChild?.literal);
    }

    // p tags
    if (event.entering && node.type === 'text') {
      console.log('p', '--', node?.literal);
    }
  }
});
```

For the above markdown the output I got on the console.

[image: hgjg]

You can see that, the first `h1` returned is *Common mark is*, but it should be actually `# Comman mark is **just great**`

Same thing for p tag, how can I solve this problem?

See live - https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vegggl?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = {
  title: /^#\s+.+/,
  heading: /^#+\s+.+/,
  custom: /\$\$\s*\w+/,
  ol: /\d+\.\s+.*/,
  ul: /\*\s+.*/,
  task: /\*\s+\[.]\s+.*/,
  blockQuote: /\>.*/,
  table: /\|.*/,
  image: /\!\[.+\]\(.+\).*/,
  url: /\[.+\]\(.+\).*/,
  codeBlock: /\`{3}\w+.*/,
};

const isTitle = (str) => regex.title.test(str);
const isHeading = (str) => regex.heading.test(str);
const isCustom = (str) => regex.custom.test(str);
const isOl = (str) => regex.ol.test(str);
const isUl = (str) => regex.ul.test(str);
const isTask = (str) => regex.task.test(str);
const isBlockQuote = (str) => regex.blockQuote.test(str);
const isImage = (str) => regex.image.test(str);
const isUrl = (str) => regex.url.test(str);
const isCodeBlock = (str) => regex.codeBlock.test(str);

export function getMdTitle(md) {
  if (!md) return "";
  let tokens = md.split("\n");
  for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    if (isTitle(tokens[i])) return tokens[i];
  }
  return "";
}

export function getMdDescription(md) {
  if (!md) return "";
  let tokens = md.split("\n");
  for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    if (
      isHeading(tokens[i]) ||
      isCustom(tokens[i]) ||
      isOl(tokens[i]) ||
      isUl(tokens[i]) ||
      isTask(tokens[i]) ||
      isBlockQuote(tokens[i]) ||
      isImage(tokens[i]) ||
      isUrl(tokens[i]) ||
      isCodeBlock(tokens[i])
    )
      continue;

    return tokens[i];
  }
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already in the [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) world, I suggest you check out the [unified collective's](https://github.com/unifiedjs/collective#teams) [remark](https://remark.js.org/) and [rehype](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype#readme) processors. These processors support parsing [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) respectively to/from [syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). All such processors in the [unified collective](https://github.com/unifiedjs/collective#teams) support custom and third-party '*plugins*' that enable you to inspect and manipulate the intermediary [syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Powerful stuff. Bit of a learning curve though. However, at some point, [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) breaks down with [non-regular languages like markdown](https://dannykong12.com/blog/writing-a-markdown-compiler-part-1.html). [Syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) can save the day.